# How to print out error messages into terminal screen while doing pipes (linux bash)

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stderr

In linux bash terminal, the command I want to run is of the form: `cmd | cmd2 > somefile.txt`.

However, I also want error message in cmd to be shown in terminal screen. So this is different from redirecting stderr to stdout. What is the way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with writing to stderr?

Answer (score 2):

Error messages written to standard error will not be sent to the piped command. I mean if your command is:

```
cmd | cmd2
```

then only the `stdout` messages from `cmd` will be piped to `cmd2` and not `stderr` messages.

Here is an example I used. I tried `cat`ing a non-existing file and tried `grep`ing some text:

```
$ cat non-existing-file.txt | grep something > grepped-text.txt
cat: non-existing-file.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: So leaving the command as it is will allow me to see error messages in cmd? Also, does this mean that I am able to see error messages from both cmd and cmd2 without changing my command?

Comment: If error messages are written to standard out, your only choice is to build a pipeline involving `grep` and `tee` to identify and reroute error messages to standard error yourself.